# Copying ANIMATED keyframes from active to group (Ridged body)

Tags: physics, keyframes

I have a scene set up with fractured objects and ridged body physics. What I am trying to do is set up the physics to start later in the scene using keyframes on either the ANIMATED or the DYNAMIC options. I am running into a problem where I can set up the keyframes great on the active object, but when I hit COPY FROM ACTIVE to apply to the rest of my fractured group objects, the keyframes don't move over with the rest of the data. Is there an easy way to send the keyframes to the rest of the selected objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you need to do is use **copy animation data**. Do this by selecting all your objects, the active should be the one you want to copy the key frames from, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>>*Animation Data* to copy the keyframes.

*Note:* This will copy all animation data, so if you have other keyframs like location or scale, this will be copied two